# object backchat is not a member of io package in scala play webSockets

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, websocket, akka

I am new to Play framework WebSockets. I have made a simple chat application using Akka in Play 2.5.3 and Scala. Now I want to unit test it.

After googling around a lot, I used following in my test class for testing the webSocket connection :

```
package test

import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import org.scalatestplus.play._
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import io.backchat.hookup._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.libs.json._

case object Connected
case class JsonMessage(json:JsValue)
case class TextMessage(text:String)



class HomeControllerTest extends PlaySpec {
   "Application " should {

     "Test WebSocket" in new WithServer(port = 9000) {

       val hookupClient = new DefaultHookupClient(HookupClientConfig(URI.create("ws://localhost:9000"))) {
        val messages = ListBuffer[String]()

        def receive = {
          case Connected =>
            println("Connected")


          case JsonMessage(json) =>
            println("Json message = " + json)

          case TextMessage(text) =>
            messages += text
            println("Text message = " + text)
        }

        connect() onSuccess {
          case Success => send("Hello Server")
        }

        }

        hookupClient.messages.contains("Hello Client") must beTrue.eventually

     }
   }
}
```

But when i run it, it gives me a lot of errors.But the major error is **object backchat is not a member of io package**. I have imported it from seeing what others did on internet. But am not sure if i need to add a dependency also in my build.sbt file?

Also suggest if there is a better way to unit test the webSocket connection using Play framework and Akka in Scala.

**Edited**

when i added `libraryDependencies += "io.backchat.hookup" %% "hookup" % "0.2.2"` in build.sbt and did "activator test"
it gave below errors on console:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: io.backchat.hookup#hookup_2.11;0.2.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      io.backchat.hookup:hookup_2.11:0.2.2 (/home/aniketp/workspace/myAkka1/build.sbt#L63-64)
[warn]        +- myakkachat:myakkachat_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.backchat.hookup#hookup_2.11;0.2.2: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:191)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:168)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:133)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:128)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:125)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:168)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1439)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1435)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$90.apply(Defaults.scala:1470)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$90.apply(Defaults.scala:1468)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1473)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1467)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1490)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1417)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.backchat.hookup#hookup_2.11;0.2.2: not found
```

Comment: Iff backchat is a library you are depending on, then you need to add the dependency to build.sbt

Comment: Yes. But i can't find the dependency part of backchat that i should add in build.sbt

Comment: I added {libraryDependencies += "io.backchat.rl" % "rl_2.9.2" % "0.3.3"} to my build.sbt and even tried with  importing its jar to my project . But the problem persists.

Comment: What is the error? Have you tried withi this: ```libraryDependencies += "io.backchat.hookup" %% "hookup" % "0.2.2"```? If nothing helps, run ```sbt clean compile``` and post the output.

Comment: hey @rethab i have edited my post for your question. Please see changes.